# Need help for a specific java printing

Tags: java, printf

So i have this program:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){ 
    int y=(int)Math.pow(4,i); 
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

How can i print it like this:

```
   4
  16
  64
 256
1024
```

(Before one digit number it should be 3 spaces,
  2 digit 2 spaces, 3 digit 1 space).

Thank you :D

Comment: What is the relation between the loop index and the number of spaces? Figure that out and you will know how many spaces to print at each iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%4d\n", y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.format("%4d\n", y);
```

The only catch is if you change your loop to generate numbers with more than 4 digits, (for example, i <= 7), then you'll get:

```
   4
  16
  64
 256
1024
4096
16384
```

You'll need to then calculate the number of digits in the largest number you'll generate:

```
final int MAX_LOOP = 7;

for(int i=1; i<= MAX_LOOP; i++){
    int y=(int)Math.pow(4,i);
    System.out.format("%" + MAX_LOOP + "d\n", y);
}
```

Result:

```
    4
   16
   64
  256
 1024
 4096
16384
```